# .Net Core - Selectively allow traffic to go over HTTP?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a api that serve multiple features. Some of the endpoints provide information that are public and not sensitive at all (images, bus stop locations, street names, etc). There are no cookies being transited also.

These transfers account for over 40% of the total traffic. On a blind-controlled test, the end user perception of responsiveness is significant, aka testers reported that they felt the http-only app is faster.

By default, my api forces all traffic to go over HTTPS, but I would like to allow a few, specific endpoints to work over regular HTTP. Is there a way to annotate the controllers/methods to do so? perhaps a way to configure this on the start-up?

Ideally I would like that the default behaviour continued to be HTTPS, and create an exclusion list that would allow HTTP, this way, new endpoints, unaware of this would still be secured.

Comment: DO. NOT. DO. IT. See, if the user is on https, there is a serious chance that the browser will pop up warnings about unsafe traffic. It at least does so for images already. Not sure about api calls beause this really is not a gain at all AND introducing a serious security risk. Remember that API requests carry the acces token and can be intercepted.

Comment: Time to forget about HTTP. Today Browser warns user, tomorrow it will block HTTP traffic. But you may put `HTTP 301 Moved Permanently` response with redirect to HTTPS on 80 port. Regular Browser will handle it correctly.

Comment: What is handling the HTTPS trafic? Wouldn't it be easier to have something like NGINX or HA-Proxy handle the SSL termination? Then you can run your whole app as http and configure the proxy to deal with which endpoints to secure and which to leave as is (assuming that still is a problem once the proxy handles the ssl stuff)

Comment: @TomTom and aepot: the user is never on a browser, always in a native app

Comment: @rene nice approach, I like it... I'll have to check with the infra-team as for the feasibility of this

Comment: Native app may get an Update and stop using HTTP.

Comment: Does not matter. I can intercept HTTP and get the access token and then your security on https is garbage. You successfully sabotage the use of https - gross neglect in case of damage.

Comment: @TomTom of course those few HTTP endpoint are open and do not require an access token

Comment: @rene indeed your approach is easier, but that would open a attack vector: internal attacks. Basically, a simple man-in-the-middle between NGINX and the application server would capture all traffic in plain text. I did like your idea, but then the security team reminded-me of this

Comment: well, if directly after the DMZ you end up on the internal network then there is something off with your zones. But this does keep the security team employed because that will keep them busy ...